# Dependency Injection discrepancy between .NET 3.1 and .NET 6.0

Tags: dependency-injection, azure-functions

We are currently encountering unexpected behaviour in our upgrade of an Azure Function from .NET 3.1 to .NET 6.

A DocumentClientProvider providing an HttpClient using a singleton implementation is registered as a singleton service. In order to perform a security check, an DelegatingHandler is added to the HttpClient. This message handler checks the existence of a custom header and if the header value is the same as the one in our SecurityContext.

```
public class DocumentClientProvider : IDocumentClientProvider
{
    private static HttpClient singletonInstance;
    private static readonly object padlock = new object();

    public DocumentClientProvider(DelegatingHandler messageHandler)
    {
        if (singletonInstance == null)
        {
            lock (padlock)
            {
                if (singletonInstance == null)
                {
                    singletonInstance =
                        new HttpClient(messageHandler);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public HttpClient GetClient() => singletonInstance;
}

public class MyMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

    public MyMessageHandler(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var securityContext = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ISecurityContext>();

        var requestHeaderValue = request.Headers.GetValues("X-Custom-Header").FirstOrDefault();
        var validHeaderValue = $"{securityContext.ClientId.ToString().ToLower()}";

        if (requestHeaderValue != validHeaderValue)
        {
            var message = $"Value of custom header is {requestHeaderValue} and it should be {validHeaderValue}.";
            throw new Exception(message);
        }

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

The SecurityContext is a small data class containing information on the identity of the caller of the function and is registered as a scoped service.

```
public class SecurityContext : ISecurityContext
{
    public Guid ClientId { get; set; }
}
```

A function simply receives a call, retrieves the HttpClient via the DocumentClientProvider and invokes an endpoint.

```
public class Function
{
    private readonly HttpClient httpClient;
    private readonly ISecurityContext securityContext;

    public Function(IDocumentClientProvider documentClientProvider, ISecurityContext securityContext)
    {
        httpClient = documentClientProvider.GetClient();
        this.securityContext = securityContext;
    }

    [FunctionName("Function")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        securityContext.ClientId = Guid.NewGuid();

        string name = req.Query["name"];
        name = name ?? "Dummy";

        var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Method = HttpMethod.Get,
            RequestUri = new Uri($"https://www.google.com/search?q={name}"),
            Headers = {
              { "X-Custom-Header", securityContext.ClientId.ToString() }
            }
        };

        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);

        return new OkObjectResult(response);
    }
}
```

The different bits are wired up as follows:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDocumentClientProvider>(ctx => 
    new DocumentClientProvider(new MyMessageHandler(ctx) { 
        InnerHandler = new HttpClientHandler() 
}));     
builder.Services.AddScoped<ISecurityContext, SecurityContext>();
```

In .NET 3.1, the function works as expected. The SecurityContext in the DelegatingHandler is resolved to the same object throughout the complete function execution. However, in .NET 6, the SecurityContext in the DelegatingHandler is resolved to a different object. The ClientId in the SecurityContext is an empty Guid and an exception is thrown.

Does anyone have any insights as to why the different versions of the Azure Functions present different behaviour related to dependency injection?

Comment: Are you trying to call a scoped object from inside a singleton? The expected  behavior here is a crash, in all .NET Core versions. Unless the scope and the lifetime of the application are the same. I suspect that's what happened here.

Comment: Besides, a singleton HttpClient is almost as bad as creating a new HttpClient instance ever time. HttpClient caches the sockets created for every server it connects to. If that server goes down or there's a DNS change (eg due to failover, load balancing) the singleton HttpClient will keep trying to connect to the wrong IP. That's why HttpClientFactory is used instead

Comment: There's no reason for the double-lock singleton code either. That's only needed in C++, where static initialization order isn't well defined. In .NET on the other hand, it is. That's why all singleton code uses just `static readonly SomeType _instance = new SomeType()` or static constructors. That `_instance` field will be initialized the very first time the type is used by any part of the code. There's no chance for 2 or more threads to modify it

Comment: I suspect what happened here is that the function didn't have a lot of traffic int its timeout window and shut down after every request, so neither the HttpClient nor the DI bug caused problems. Now either there's more traffic or the function lives for longer, resulting in attempts to use disposed objects

Comment: It's not a good idea to use the serviceProvider inside your MessageHandler directly. The message handler shouldn't know anything about the DI here. If message handler needs an instance of ISecurityContext then provide exactly that instance.

Comment: Furthermore, "Function" should't know anything about the implementation details of ISecurityContext.  If you want to use sth called "SecurityContext" you should encapsulate the details and provide a function to get the header from it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for the tip on the double-lock singleton. :-)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos In our real-life scenario, we are dealing with the DocumentClientProvider providing a CosmosClient where we want to check for the PartitionKey header value via a custom RequestHandler. Here I used HttpClient and Delegating handler to illustrate the case a bit more concise. The behaviour is the same. The CosmosClient is preferably registered as a singleton. However, the SecurityContext contains data which should be scoped to the function execution. Somehow, there is a difference in how the DI containers are built up between both versions of .NET